# Laravel 5: Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I was getting error

> Fatal error: Class 'TestCase' not found in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/myapp/tests/ExampleTest.php on line 7

while running command ***./vendor/bin/phpunit***. I read about this error and changed my composer.json and added TestCase.php file. But I'm still getting this error.

My files:

composer.json

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```

TestCase.php

```
<?php
namespace Tests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
   use CreatesApplication;
}
```

ExampleTest.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testExample()
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel 5 are you running? You can check the version you're using with `php artisan --version`. On 5.4.30, the example unit test also has a `use Tests\TestCase;` statement and is namespaced to `namespace Tests\Unit;`

Comment: @Chris Forrence I am using 5.3.31 version

Comment: The TestCase.php file you have matches Laravel 5.4's format (with the namespace and trait usage); add `namespace Tests;` to the top of your ExampleTest.php file if ExampleTest.php and TestCase.php are in the same folder

Comment: @Chris Forrence Everything working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add namespace to your ExampleTest class :

```
namespace Tests;
```